# How can I concatenate two things within a FreeMarker template?

Tags: java, freemarker

I'm a beginner when it comes to Java, but I've been faced with modifying an existing piece of software. I'd appreciate any help I can get with it.

The FreeMarker template I have makes a request to a restful API, and gets back some XML representing the twenty most recent replies on a forum. It then iterates over them, displaying one after the other.

```
  <#assign recent = rest(restContext + "/boards/id/352/replies/recent").messages />
```

There is a separate API endpoint to get the twenty most recent threads posted. Both calls return identically-formatted XML.

What I would like to do is combine those two things into one, so that I can display "most recent posts and threads". I would sort the combined item by `response.messages.post_time`.

My question is: how exactly would I do this within the template, which is the only piece of the code I have access to? Is `rest` something built into FreeMarker? I'm out of my depth and would appreciate some help, Java is still new to me.

Comment: `rest` is not built into FreeMarker. So what's `recent`? A list of messages? If so, have you tried concatenating that list with the other list with `+`?

Answer (score 1):

This looks very familiar...Lithium REST API v1 request, isn't it?

What you can do is basically merge the two response objects at the right place (v1 tends to be not very intuitive with it's response structures...) BUT normal rest() context object responses cannot be simply merged in FreeMarker (with + on the same data type, e.g. hash or sequence), so what you need is Lithium v14.12 or greater and the restd() context object...your code should look something like that:

```
<#assign replies = restd("/replies/recent", "json")?replace("\\/", "/")?replace(':null', ':"null"')?eval />
<#assign threads = restd("/topics/recent", "json")?replace("\\/", "/")?replace(':null', ':"null"')?eval />
<#assign merged = replies.response.messages.message + threads.response.messages.message />
<#assign objects = [] />

<#list merged as obj>
    <#-- to sort we have to create our own object with a more simple structure (right now the post_time is deeply nested and not accessible with ?sort_by) -->
    <#assign object = {
        "subject": obj.subject.$,
        "href": obj.href,
        "post_time": obj.post_time.$,
        "author": obj.author.login.$
    } />

    <#assign objects = objects + [object] />
</#list>

<#-- now we can sort the objects we created above, you probably want the newest objects on top, right? if not, just remove the ?reverse -->
<#assign objects = objects?sort_by("post_time")?reverse />

<ul>
    <#-- now we list again (yes...) over the sorted objects and output them -->
    <#list objects as obj>
    <li><a href="${obj.href}">${obj.subject}</a> on ${obj.post_time} from ${obj.author}</li>
    </#list>
</ul>
```

The explanation of the code above is basically that we need something from the REST API of Lithium that can be converted to a "normal" FreeMarker object/datatype, JSON happens to be more or less like FreeMarker Hashes/Sequences, with a few exceptions (like null values...), that's why we need these ?replace build-ins to "sanitize" the incoming JSON string and then call ?eval (yes, it's evil, but sometimes we need evil to fight evil =D) on that string to create FreeMarker objects from it.

After that we can simply merge the objects at the right place (in your case the response.messages.message node) and create a new object from them, which we then can use to template our component.

The sorting part makes it necessary to basically "re-structure" the objects we just merged, as the FreeMarker build-in ?sort_by() cannot deal with deeply nested objects as we have them right now...so we loop (list) trough the merged objects and create a new sequence of objects with the properties we need from them, after that we can use ?sort_by on that new sequence of objects to sort it by the desired field. Then the sequence is sorted and ready to be templated in another loop.